# How to use angular.fromJson in php

Tags: php, json, angularjs

How to convert `angular.toJson` data in php controller

> angular.fromJson

can't be used in php so i tried to use `json_decode`  but its returning

> Disallowed Key Characters.

Please help me

Comment: What's the input you're trying to decode? What are the "disallowed key characters"?

Comment: thank you for reply...
i have encoded data using angular.toJson  and pass to php function there i want to decode that so i have decoded data using json_decode it returns disallowed characters in the console

Answer (score 0):

angular.toJson(obj, 0);

What input are you giving to the function?

> This function only works with UTF-8 encoded strings.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php